# Get websocket connection to WhatsApp using Python or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, python, websocket, whatsapp

I copy the websocket request from the chrome network tab and try to use it as fetch and clearly is not working because fetch only support `HTTP(S)`.

Is there a way I can connect to WhatsApp websocket connection by either `Python` or `JavaScript`?

Comment: Perhaps a CORS policy prevent that. Mybe its only possible from "web.whatsapp.com" to establisch a ws connection to "wss://web.whatsapp.com/ws"

Comment: @Marc I tried on the same domain, no success. I'm sure there's something related to cookie or session authentication which I should include in headers (there's `wa_csrf` but js does not allow to send custom headers in websocket connection).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know If this will help, you can always use WebSocket in node.js . Similarly, ***socketio*** module is available in python.

I tried this in my local machine but the socket server throwed an unexpected Forbiden 403 error.

Anyway, this is the example:

```
const WebSocket = require('ws')
var socket = new WebSocket("wss://web.whatsapp.com/ws")

socket.onopen = (e)=>console.log("connected")

socket.onmessage = (e)=>console.log("msg",e)

socket.onerror = (e)=>console.log("error",e)
```

[WebSocket](https://github.com/websockets/ws) Github repo link

Comment: That would throw the `403 Forbidden` cause you should authenticate yourself against the WhatsApp.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the flask-socketio and for javascript socket library. The steps are to connect and then send data to the function mentioned. You need to read the documentation as it is pretty simple.

Comment: Oh dude, you didn't read the question carefully. I know how to use websockets in either of languages but don't know how to connect to whatsapp and authorize myself to get the event streams.

Comment: Why "flask-scoketio" ?

Comment: In that way you will have it continuous server that listens to it using python flask as a web server.

Answer (score 0):

You can get connect to socket in chrome using

```
let socket = new WebSocket("wss://web.whatsapp.com/ws");


socket.onopen = (e)=>console.log("connected")

socket.onmessage = (e)=>console.log("msg",e)

socket.onerror = (e)=>console.log("error",e)
```

but you can't listern messages.

Comment: That would throw the 403 Forbidden cause you should authenticate yourself against the WhatsApp.